# Picture HTML tag with TypeScript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image

What is the "type" I need extends to use a tag picture with React and TS? Like the example:

`export interface MyInterfaceextends React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {}`

I need to extend something suitable to the picture html tag.

Tried use

```
React.ImgHTMLAttributes
```

but with no success.

Comment: can you add an example of the code?

Comment: From the compiled sources: `JSX.IntrinsicElements.picture: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>`